# Ansible Where private key should be placed?

Tags: ansible, rsync

The scenario:
We have 2 servers and use private key to communicate via ssh
Server 1 (stage)
Server 2 (production)
Inventory file:

```
[server]
server1.com
server2.com
```

Both servers has default username "ubuntu"
For now we need put private key on Local Machine, Server 1, Server 2, on the same path. For example:
On Local Machine : /tmp/key/privatekey (private key to remote server 1)
On Server 1 : /tmp/key/privatekey (private key to remote server 2)
On Server 2 : /tmp/key/privatekey (private key to remote server 1)

```
- name: copy archived file to another remote server using rsync.
      synchronize: mode=pull src=/home/{{ user }}/packages/{{ package_name }}.tar.gz dest=/tmp/{{ package_name }}.tar.gz archive=yes
      delegate_to: "{{ production_server }}"
      tags: release
```

Ansible playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory --extra-vars "host=server[0] user=ubuntu" --private-key=/tmp/key/privatekey playbook.yml --tags "release"
```

Executing ansible playbook on local machine will remote Server 1 to copy archived file on Server 1 to Server 2.

That worked as we expected, but It's ridiculous, we have to place private key on the same path on 3 machines (local, server 1, server 2). What if we want to place private key on different path? or the user want to use different account/username for server 1 and server 2?

I've tried modifiying inventory, providing user and auth key for server 2. I placed private key under /home/ubuntu/key/ on server 1:

```
[server]
server1.com
server2.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ubuntu/key/privatekey    ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

then run the same ansible playbook command above. The result, server 1 could not remote server 2

What if we want to place private key on different path? or the user want to use different account/username for server 1 and server 2?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making your life much harder than it needs to be.  If I assume you're using the user 'ubuntu' and standard RSA keys

1. Take your PPK pairs and put them in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa and /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on each machine.  These are the default locations for PPK files the sshd daemon will look.
2. Write a playbook to deploy the public key (using the authorized_keys module) from your control machine to your target machines.  Since you're sharing keys they are all the same.
3. If you want to do communication between server1 and server2 via delegate_to you'll have to update the ssh_config for the ubuntu user.  Your options here are to turn off host key/known host checking OR add the appropriate entries to known_hosts.  The former (less secure) can be done by adding a /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config file and the latter (more secure) can be done via ssh-keyscan (see https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts)

Part of the issue here is that when you use delegate_to I don't think the whole ssh connection logic,that would normally be constructed on the control machine, doesn't get propagated to the delegate machine.

Also I would not put your private keys out in the tmp directory

Hope this helps